# Extreme drop in activity/traffic lately?

Tags: discussion

"Stack Overflow" is by many seen as "basically Stack Exchange", with the others being somewhat of "bonus categories". Even if it was often nothing but downvotes and toxic trolls, my questions used to get quick "responses" of some kind.

Lately, it seems as if my question is entirely "hidden away" and doesn't even show up among the latest questions. As such, it doesn't even get one page view of traffic. I'm not sure if this is temporary or permanent, but I've had many questions just "fade away into oblivion" this way recently.

How can this be explained? I may be living under a rock, but I'm not aware of one single other website on the Internet where you can ask questions which isn't either a ghost town, impossible to register on, or completely full of people I want nothing to do with.

Basically, has even "Stack Overflow" died now or what?

Comment: There were just over 15,000 posts yesterday, pretty much the same as for the last few months.

Comment: The traffic is less in December. People are taking holidays at the end of the year and are less active on the internet.

Comment: if your post isn't showing up among the latest questions, that'd suggest either A: they aren't good questions and are being downvoted, or B: there is in fact a lot of activity... if not a mix of both.

Comment: Are you sure the content you are posting is interesting and useful for the community?

Comment: It is not the lack of traffic that affects you, it is enormous increase in traffic that does.

Comment: If you'd like your question to have more attention, you can try a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: The lack of eyeballs may actually be in your benefit, because from the looks of your user CP... you may be inches away from a question ban. I would stop asking new questions if I were you, try to see if you can improve existing ones.

Answer (score 25):

One reason why your questions might not get much attention is because you are using wrong tags. I have just corrected one question and added the appropriate PHP tag.

Another reason might be that your titles are not summarizing the issue clearly.

When asking questions make sure the topic you post about is new and useful to the community. Otherwise people will not be interested in it and it will not attract a lot of views.

And finally, the systemic problem is that there's just too many questions being asked. People treat Stack Overflow like some kind of help desk and come here with all their problems. Your good questions might be getting lost in the deluge of poor questions.